# Visability of static resourses in Thymeleaf with using Spring security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have a directory hierarchy like this:

```
-resources
|
|-static
|  |-css
|  |-js
|-templates
   |-error
   |-fragments
```

And This cofigure:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").not().fullyAuthenticated()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/main").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/registration").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/main")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
    }
```

And I need some help: 1) My static resources are not visible until authorization
2) Redirect to css or js files after authorization

Please help me. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {
        "/css/**",
        "/js/**",
        "/images/**",
};
//...
    http
        .authorizeRequests().
        antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).
        permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
//...
```

Comment: You're welcome. :)
I was also a beginner in Spring Boot and Thymeleaf months ago and I'm glad I can help others.

Answer (score 1):

You should create public folder in your resources folder and Spring will serve files which are placed in `/css/**`, `/js/**`, `/images/**` folders without auth, to everyone.

If you place img.jpg in images folder like that `src/main/resources/public/images/img.jpg` it will be accessible at http://localhost:8080/images/img.jpg